# Array is only printing the last stored value and array element removal only replaces element

Tags: java, arrays

Does anyone know why is that when I print the last message ("report header..etc etc") the count on the list updates, but I'm only printing the last person's input values?

Also, how can I make so that only if the person has 30 or more credits or less than 90 will their name and credits be stored in the array, otherwise do nothing with the inputs?

Lastly, in the 'admin review' prompt portion, if I type in a name that matches an input, it should remove that name, but in my current code it only replaces the name with what I entered..

```
  final int MAX_ON_LIST = 50;

  String[] stuName = new String[1];
  int[] numCredits = new int[1];

  int currentSize = 0;

  String question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done entering students? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");

  while (question.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

     for (int i = 0; i < stuName.length; i++) {
        do {
           try {
              stuName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter student name:");        
              currentSize++;
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              stuName[i] = "";
           }
           if (stuName[i].equals("")) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be blank");
           }
        } while (stuName[i].equals(""));
     }


     for (int i = 0; i < numCredits.length; i++) {

        do {
           try {
              numCredits[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter # of completed credits:"));
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              numCredits[i] = -1;
           }
           if (numCredits[i] < 0) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "# of credits can't be less than 0");
           }
        } while (numCredits[i] < 0);
     }

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(stuName) + "\n" + Arrays.toString(numCredits));

     question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done entering students? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");

  }




  String nxtQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done with the admin. review? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");



  while (nxtQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

     String searchValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a name:");;
     int position = 0;
     boolean found = false;

     while (position < stuName.length && !found) {
        if (stuName[position].equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)) {
           found = true;
        }
        else {
           ++position;
        }
     }
     if (found) {
        stuName[1] = stuName[currentSize - 1];
        --currentSize;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(stuName) + "\n" + Arrays.toString(numCredits));
     }
     else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name not on list");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(stuName) + "\n" + Arrays.toString(numCredits));

     }

     nxtQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done with the admin. review? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");
  }



  if (nxtQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("y")); 
  {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
           "Report Header\n\n" + "# of student's on list: " + currentSize + "\nNames: " + Arrays.toString(stuName) +
           "\nCredits: " + Arrays.toString(numCredits));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you go through all the pain of using arrays here while List (ArrayList or LinkedList) would suit your needs much better. I'm assuming this is some sort of a task where you must use arrays. Otherwise the whole code should be rewritten.

As correctly mentioned above, arrays don't change size - both of your arrays always have size of 1 all the time. This also results in index out of bounds exception if you enter more than one student and then in admin you enter the name of last student.

The name of last student is the only name saved, that's why it's the only name printed.

In order to only store person with credit >=30 and <=90 you can use a simple if.

Also note the code in the final part of your program:

```
if (nxtQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
{
// Do something
}
```

Due to semicolon right after if the if is doing nothing.
The part in curly braces (where I've put "Do something" comment) will always get executed, it's separate from the if. (Java allows you to put blocks of code in curly braces in order to limit scope of local variables).

P.S. Here's a slightly better version (at least it works):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_ON_LIST = 50;
    final int bottomCreditsLimit = 30;
    final int topCreditsLimit = 90;

    String[] stuName = new String[0];
    int[] numCredits = new int[0];

    String question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done entering students? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");

    while (question.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && stuName.length < MAX_ON_LIST) {
        String stuNameInput = "";
        do {
            stuNameInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter student name:").trim();
            if (stuNameInput.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be blank");
            }
        } while (stuNameInput.equals(""));

        int numCreditsInput = -1;
        do {
            try {
                numCreditsInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter # of completed credits:").trim());
                if (numCreditsInput < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "# of credits can't be less than 0");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input integer value");
            }
        } while (numCreditsInput < 0);

        if (numCreditsInput >= bottomCreditsLimit && numCreditsInput <= topCreditsLimit) {
            stuName = Arrays.copyOf(stuName, stuName.length + 1);
            stuName[stuName.length - 1] = stuNameInput;
            numCredits = Arrays.copyOf(numCredits, numCredits.length + 1);
            numCredits[numCredits.length - 1] = numCreditsInput;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(stuName) + "\n" + Arrays.toString(numCredits));
        }

        question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done entering students? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");
    }

    String nxtQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done with the admin. review? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");

    while (nxtQuestion.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        String searchValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a name:").trim();
        int position = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < stuName.length; i++) {
            if (stuName[i].equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (position >= 0) {
            stuName[position] = stuName[stuName.length - 1];
            stuName = Arrays.copyOf(stuName, stuName.length - 1);
            numCredits[position] = numCredits[numCredits.length - 1];
            numCredits = Arrays.copyOf(numCredits, numCredits.length - 1);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name not on list");
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(stuName) + "\n" + Arrays.toString(numCredits));

        nxtQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you done with the admin. review? (Enter 'Y' or 'N')");
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Report Header\n\n" + "# of student's on list: " + stuName.length + "\nNames: " + Arrays.toString(stuName)
            + "\nCredits: " + Arrays.toString(numCredits));
}
```

Comment: How can I set the size of the arrays so they are only as big as however many times the user gets prompted? But without asking how many times the user wants to be prompted beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Each of your arrays has a single element. Every time you add a name, you're putting it into the same position in the array.

```
String[] stuName = new String[1];
int[] numCredits = new int[1];
```

This loop always has exactly one pass, with i = 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < stuName.length; i++) {
```

Alternatives include:

- Create a `java.util.List` of students, which grows as needed with each call to List.add().
- Create a `java.util.Map` of students from name to value.

Comment: How can I make it so if the user only wants to enter 5 names, it will display those 5 names? Or however many names the user wants to enter, but the max is 50 names

Comment: One way to establish a maximum would be to add an additional condition in the your topmost, outermost loop -- which you might want to consider making a `do-while` instead of a `while`. You can display all the entered names by iterating through them with a loop. Currently, your code searches for specific entered names.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop pre-compiles so you need to set stuName to something before engaging the loop.

Comment: Can you explain this further? So I should set stuName to something between the while and for loop?

Comment: Like the above said; A do while loop might be better than a for loop if the single pass is still the issue.